# Update AD Users based on CSV (lack of cell data in a row)

Tags: powershell

I have following script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv C:\ADUpdate\ADUsers.csv

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SAMAccountName -eq '$($user.SAMAccountName)'" -Properties * |
    Set-ADUser -Title $($user.title) -Office $($user.office) -OfficePhone $($user.OfficePhone) -Mobile $($user.mobile)
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I think that it is because I have a CSV file which lacks of cell data in a row. So I don't have

- SamAccountname
- title
- Office
- OfficePhone
- Mobile

But I have an Excel file which has all attributes like normal Excel file.

```
A B C D
1
2
3
```

Is it any way to tell PowerShell to use information from other rows etc.?

Comment: *"Is it any way to tell powershell to use information from other rows etc.?"* The answer to your question is, of course, "yes". But I doubt that this is what you actually wanted to know, so how about you show us what your data file actually looks like. Maybe then we can provide advice on how to extract information from it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling data, your `.csv` should look something like this in Excel and saved in the `CSV Comma Delimited` format:

```
SamAccountName    title    office      OfficePhone    mobile
DarthVader        Sith     D Star      555555555      5555555555
LukeSkywalker     Jedi     Tattooine   1234567890     1234567890
```